# WPF and Dropbox

Tags: c#, wpf

I've been looking for some information about the subject, the thing is  I'm trying to open, read, write files in dropbox thru a WPF app. So far I found this video  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fcT-Jt8rcdY  and the problem is that it uses windows forms and also has to introduce username and password to login. I just want to use dropbox as a tool to save some files in the cloud without loging everytime the program want to acces to dropbox. Any ideas?

Comment: Using the Dropbox API it is just a matter of interfacing it with WPF. The code for the API will not change. You will have to adapt it to WPF yourself.

Comment: So what have you tried? There isn't a clear question here, and I think it's likely to get closed unless you provide some more details and a more specific question

Comment: You've got 2 options... 1) Run dropbox on the machine, user WPF to write files to the dropbox folder 2) Use the dropbox Api (with credentials) and store the files directly. You don't have to prompt the user for creds every time, there are a number of places you can store them with each with a traddeoff between security/ease of use

Answer (score 0):

You can use DropBox Linker, a library for using DropBox in .NET WPF application.

http://dropboxlinker.codeplex.com